# Independent views or different methods for a page?

Tags: backbone.js

I have an application that the unique thing that uses Backbone is a navigator that highlights where the user are. I mean, it's a "breadcrumb" to guide him to locate himself.

But now, I'm implementing internationalization and I need to identify which language the user is navigating in – and I would to do that with Backbone as well.

Until now, my view is this:

```
var breadcrumbView = new BreadcrumbView({
    scope: '#{@scope}'
});
```

Then I ask: it's better to create another view just for the internationalization fashion or the right thing to do is aggregate this two resources into a `HomeView`? E.g.

```
var home = new HomeView;
home.Breadcrumb.create('#{@scope}');
home.Internationalization.create();
```

Comment: What your `Internationalization` will do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the **right solution**. Let's go?

### Understanding the real problem

The meaning of "internationalization" in my question refers to highlighting which language the user is using. Let's suppose that the "current" language is `en-US`, then we highlight it in the menu of languages.

### Extracting the solution

Firstly, I searched on Wikipedia the follow explanation about **views**:

> *A view is told by the controller all the information it needs for generating an output representation to the user. It can also provide generic mechanisms to inform the controller of user input.*
>
> [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Secondly, I know that `internationalization` and `breadcrumbs` are components of my view. *Of my view*. You see? These two "features" aren't the view itselves – they're just components that compose it.

### Implementing the solution

Based on the knowledge we acquired, is simple to say that **internationalization** and **breadcrumbs** should to be methods of my `HomeView`.

Translating this into code, this is the right thing to do:

```
var home = new HomeView;
home.Breadcrumb.create('#{@scope}');
home.Internationalization.create();
```